# Java 8 stream: list to flat map grouped by

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have following situation. (pseudocode)

```
class A {
  id;
  List<B> bs;
}

class B {}
```

I wonder how to convert List os As -> Map of Bs

```
List<A> as;

// the Map key is A.id (Map<A.id, List<B>>)
Map<Integer, List<B>> bs = as.stream()
                       .map(a ->a.getBs())
                       .collect(// I dont know what to add here ???);
```

Comment: `Map<Integer, B>` or `Map<Integer, List<B>>` ?

Comment: what are you going to do with the few values for one key?

Comment: sorry I meant Map<Integer, List<B>>, (corrected)

Comment: Here i have given a lot of examples for that. You may find it useful for your question  https://www.javagists.com/java-8-streams-list-to-map-examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want sometime like this:

```
 Map<Integer, List<B>> bs = as.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getId, A::getBs));
```

Comment: Assuming `id` is unique...

Comment: @shmosel agree...

Comment: My interpretation was that OP wanted to group and flatten multiple `bs`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @shmosel Indeed, the initial question context that was and the question title still fall in the line of intuition there.